# Binding combobox data bult from a list to a property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a `combo box` and button as such

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding MessageTypesList}" 
           DisplayMemberPath="MessageType" 
           SelectedValue="MessageType" />
<Button Content="Search" 
        Command="{Binding Path=SearchMessageTypes}" 
        x:Name="SearchMessageTypeButton"/>
```

The `MessageTypesList` list is generated from a SQL query and once the Message Type is selected from the list the Search button needs to pass the selected value to a string property in my ViewMainModel.

When I debug the application the value passed to the MessageType property is always NULL. I have this working for a similar date time searchs but cant see how to pass the MessageType value in my XAML to the MessageType propery form binding generated lists.

Answer (score 2):

You should bind the `SelectedValue` property to a property in your viewmodel.

Answer (score 2):

Create a property in your viewmodel:

```
public MessageType SelectedType {get;set;}
```

Bind selectedItem to this property in XAML:

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding MessageTypesList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedType, Mode=TwoWay" />
```